# How To Receive Values From Servlet On JSP Page

Tags: jsp, servlets, intellij-idea

I try to do an exercise in Java EE but I fail to see the information in my JSP page.

I send from my servlet to jsp page, a catalog. I have to view each product in my JSP page that way but I can not retrieve the information.

I must to display product in catalog without use taglib.

Below, the HTML of the resulting page should be as follows (afficheCatalogue.jsp):

```
<div class="product number one"> 
<table> 
<tr> 
<td rowspan="2"><img src="http://i2.cdscdn.com/pdt2/3/0/0/1/180x180/samsu60es6300.jpg"/></td> <td><a class="nom" href="/miagetp1/AfficheProduit?id=P3">SAMSUNG UE60ES6300 TV LED 3D </a></td> 
</tr> 
<tr>
test
<td class="prix">1 749,99&nbsp;&euro;</td>
</tr> 
<tr> <td colspan="2" class="desc">Téléviseur LED 3D 60'' ( 152 cm ) - Triple tuner HD : TNT / Câble et Satellite - HDTV 1080p - Résolution 1920 x 1080 - CMR 200Hz
</td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
</div>
```

Below, the code, I use Intellij:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/st7tb4bnnf0cfha/exemple.zip

Thanks for your help,

Nikolas

Comment: do some more practice, and look through again the tutorial, if not interested in taglib then [scriptlets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaou.html) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you uploaded (exemple.zip), the afficheCatalogue.jsp is essentially empty.

This is what I see in the afficheCatalogue.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="bean.Catalogue" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="CSS/styles.css">
<div class="titre">Catalogue</div>
<br><br>





</body>
</html>
```

I don't see any way the JSP will be able to pull any information to display.  There is no code to display the request attributes that you are setting in the servlet.  From what I can see, this JSP file will always display an empty page.

Here is a rough code snippet that you can use to pull the values from your request attribute...which is a list:

```
<c:forEach items="${produits}" var="items">
    Item Key: ${items.key}<br>
    Item Name: <b>${items.value.nom}</b><br>   
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I tried to write code but I can not make a loop to display in a table, the product name, image, price and description. How can I do this?

My servlet sends request.setAttribute ("products", Catalogue.getInstance () getListproduit ().); to my jsp page.

Thanks,

Nikolas

Comment: My code example here is very rough, but you can use JSTL's c:forEach tag to iterate through your products. Something like this:'<c:forEach items="${produits}" var="items">
    Item Key: ${items.key}<br>
    Item Name: <b>${items.value.nom}</b><br>   
</c:forEach>'

Comment: Thanks for your help but I can't use JSTL, only java !!

Comment: If you can't use JSTL, then you'll have to use a scriptlet in your JSP to use java code.  You can get the request attribute that you set in your servlet in the JSP with a request.getAttribute("produits"); call.  If you want to write something out that will be rendered on the browser page from within the scriptlet you can use the out.write("your text"); call.

Comment: Thanks for your help, nicolas

Comment: you're welcome!  If you are satisfied with my answer, it is helpful if you mark my answer as the accepted answer.  thanks